# Is it good to create an object inside a loop?

Tags: java, json, object, resultset

I am trying to get data from db and present that data in json object. to represent the data into json object i'm trying to iterate from resultset object and add result into a list. But is it good to create a class object inside while loop. In my case it is going to create more than 100 objects.

```
Emp emp;
List<Emp> empList = new ArrayList<Emp>();
while(rs.next()){
    emp = new Emp();
    emp.setEMPLOYEE_ID(rs.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID"));
    emp.setFIRST_NAME(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
    emp.setLAST_NAME(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
    empList.add(emp);
}
System.out.println(empList.size());
ObjectWriter ob = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
json = ob.writeValueAsString(empList);
```

Comment: what you're doing looks pretty normal and is fine.  Might I make a suggestion?  First, if serving web content, close/release your resultset, statement, and database connection before writing the JSON response.  You want to avoid holding a database connection while writing the response, as response writing can block.

Comment: The question shouldn't be "is it ok", the question should be "is it necessary"? If **yes** (like in this example in your question), then *yes* it is ok, because it is required. If **no**, then it isn't ok. So this question is context dependent.

Comment: Also, consider utilizing constructors

Comment: The variable `emp` should not be declared outside the loop in this example. You should declare variables to the narrowest scope in which they apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually better to create the object inside the loop. Java optimizes memory usage for short-lived objects. Memory allocation time for an object is next to zero, and collection time is zero, other than the overhead of running a minor GC at all. GC time in minor collections is proportional to the number of live objects, so the more objects that die, the faster the collection. This also keeps them out of the tenured generation, which takes longer to clean up. So not only is it "fine" to create the object inside the loop, but you should do so, and indeed should declare it inside the loop. In your code example, `emp` has too wide a scope. You can also use the empty diamond operator, `<>`, as the generifier for `ArrayList` in the declaration of `empList` (which should not have the word `List` in its name, but be a plural like `employees`).

Comment: I asked this because when ever we use sonar or PMD this line of code is causing violations. If this is the normal behavior then what's wrong with sonar and PMD rules?

Comment: What violations do they report, specifically, on what line?

Comment: I am going to guess that it's the line `Emp emp;` and the violation has to do with the scope of the variable.